# autoresizesSubviews

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

The iOS6 [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) says on the property autoresizesSubviews:

> A Boolean value that determines whether the receiver automatically resizes its subviews when its bounds change.
>   Discussion
>   When set to YES, the receiver adjusts the size of its subviews when **its** bounds change. The default value is YES.

To me as a non english native-speaker this is a bit unsharp. Does "its" refer to the receiver or to the subviews of the receiver?

Comment: In proper grammar of English, if the sentence was referring to the sub views of the receiver, the word "its" would be changed to their. I am curious about the mechanism of this Boolean. I wonder, if it is set to no, does that disable the auto resizing mask of all the subviews, like a view-wide instant off switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to the receiver.

If `autoResizesSubviews` is set to YES on view A, which is the superview of views B and C, then when the bounds of A is changed, A will adjust the sizes of B and C.

Comment: Oh i see, so it doesn't call sizeToFit?

Comment: There is something odd about autoresizeSubviews. I'm not a fully skilled layout master, but I do know, when this is YES, and the view contains a subview with no flexible autoresizing mask, that subview's internal subviews still get resized.  This has been my problem. Autoresizing masks that are setup to make a view rigid can be bypassed by the superview, to affect the size/layout of internal subviews. Totally counter intuitive, and enough to make me go crazy for hours.

Comment: @TomPace i m having the same problem, can u pls tell how did you solve that?

Comment: @SarimSidd I cannot remember the specific code I worked on when I was doing this. I just skimmed my Git logs from Nov 28-30, and nothing jumps out as my notated solution, but I did add in some methods about asking the subviews for their preferred dimensions.  So perhaps you could try this: make your subviews and the internal subviews all UIViewAutoresizingNone, then do any manual adjustment when the super superview's bounds are changed.

Comment: @SarimSidd  by the way I stopped using the constants. That's probably a bad idea, since they're abstracted symbols, but I doubt they'll ever change.  I just memorized the meaning and order of the values, and they're all springs when on, struts when not on.  1,2,4,8,16,32 = left, width, right, top, height, bottom.  This makes it WAY faster to type out, and easier to read with a comment explanation. So any line of code where I manually adjust the autoresizingMask looks similar to:  adbannerview.autoresizingMask = 2 + 8; // flex width and top, for bottom-docked ad banner